# Массив в массиве в массиве + цикл

Tags: php, массивы, json

Нужно получить такую структуру массива(1В1), чтобы парсить JSON'ом.

```
INACTIVE = {
    "info": {
        "id": "173",
        "price": "17",
        "steamPrice": "3920",
        "nowUsers": "124",
        "users": "180",
        "classid": "1011983344",
        "my": false
    },
    "myPlacesCount": 0,
    "users": [
        [
            "We are JATU! FEAR US AND PARISH",
            "76561197996976377",
            "32\/3285861ddf27e3caaf96969a13cf1d6569789d60_full.jpg",
            "2015-09-30 14:36:12",
            "213"
        ],
        [
            "_baser pro_",
            "76561198182263290",
            "57\/57f71b2959f31cdc1153828a2adba40c64eeae43_full.jpg",
            "2015-09-30 14:30:02",
            "33"
        ],
        [
            "Andrey_GReNT",
            "76561198108538894",
            "e6\/e6cff80119680c1f8f040d503cc9007ad05985ff_full.jpg",
            "2015-09-30 14:29:58",
            "259"
        ],
        [
            "SYSTEM_START",
            "",
            "",
            "2015-09-29 14:59:32"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Я все-таки сумел это сделать. Вот, что у меня вышло:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM *** WHERE id='".$item_id."'") or die(mysql_error());
$res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cs_lots_history WHERE id='".$lot_item_id."'") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
            $rows = array(
                'info' => array(
                'id' => $row['id'],
                'inv_id' => $row['inv_id'],
                'inv_assets' => $row['inv_assets'],
                'maxUsers' => $row['places'],
                'nowUsers' => $row['now_places'],
                'inv_name' => $row['inv_name'],
                'inv_image' => $row['inv_image'],
                'inv_rarity' => $row['inv_rarity'],
                'inv_color' => $row['inv_color'],
                'inv_type' => $row['inv_type'],
                'inv_price' => $row['inv_price'],
                'price_ticket' => $row['price_ticket'],
                ), 'myPlacesCount' => 0, "users"=>
                    $array2 = array(
                        $array3 = [
        $row2['user_personaname'],$row2['user_steamid'],$row2['user_avatarmedium'],$row2['date'],$row2['place']
                        ]
                    )
              );
        }
```

Вопрос теперь следующий. Как я могу в row2 передать все значения, которые выведу из res2 ? Второй цикл ведь прямо в массиве не сделать.
А если сделать его выше этого цикла, то в таком случае в row2 попадут только последние значения из последней строки mysql.

Т.е. мне нужно сделать все таким образом, чтобы в массив "users" попадали все значения из другой таблицы, где item_id = item_id.

Answer (score 1):

Ужас. Методом тыка все же разобрался. Получилось так.

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cs_lots WHERE id='".$lot_item_id."'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $rows = array(
        'info' => array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'inv_id' => $row['inv_id'],
        'inv_assets' => $row['inv_assets'],
        'maxUsers' => $row['places'],
        'nowUsers' => $row['now_places'],
        'inv_name' => $row['inv_name'],
        'inv_image' => $row['inv_image'],
        'inv_rarity' => $row['inv_rarity'],
        'inv_color' => $row['inv_color'],
        'inv_type' => $row['inv_type'],
        'inv_price' => $row['inv_price'],
        'price_ticket' => $row['price_ticket'],
        )
    );
}
    $res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cs_lots_history WHERE id_lot='".$lot_item_id."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $array4 = array();
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2)) {
    array_push($array4, array($row2['user_personaname'],$row2['user_steamid'],$row2['user_avatarmedium'],$row2['date'],$row2['place']));
    }
    $rows = array_merge($rows, array('myPlacesCount' => 0, 'users' => $array2=$array4));
```